# “Force update of snapshots/releases” - is this dangerous?

Tags: java, maven, repository, maven-plugin

Is “Force update of snapshots/releases” command dangerous? I mean, can I destroy something in the remote repo, if I do that? For example, if I execute this command, will I break snapshots? Do I change anything on the repositroy?

Comment: Do it, test if everything works and then commit it or check the old version out if it didn't work

Comment: I had error messages with my Pom.xml and after I forced it, the messages have disappeared, but I thought because I changed or broke something in the remote repo. It was really a relief.

Answer (score 1):

It does not change anything in remote repositories.

It just updates your local repository, possibly overwriting existing SNAPSHOTs with newer ones.

Comment: Thank you! I had error messages with my Pom.xml and after I forced it, the messages have disappeared, but I thought because I changed or broke something in the remote repo. It was really a relief.